# How do you design classes who would conceptually have an overwhelming number of "types" or subclasses?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

To elaborate on my question, the particular situation is this:

If I have a simulation or game project with, say, a `Monster` class that has different statistics as member data (`hitPointsRemaining`, `AttackDamage`, etc) and I want to have any number of different types of monsters with constant base statistics (`MaxHP`, `Speed`, etc), then I see three ways that this class will need to be used:

1. An actual class with an interface to be used for using Monster objects throughout the code (say, "`Monster`")
2. The actual "data" for the different types of monsters. (conceptually possible subclasses? although I'm certain that's not the right solution) example: Goblin, Dragon, Cyclops, etc
3. Actual instantiated `Monster` objects representing different monsters as the character meets them in the game (with possibility of multiple instances of the same type at any time)

I was wondering how most designers go about implementing this.
My thoughts were as follows:

-It doesn't make sense to make a `Monster` class and then a new subclass for every type of monster conceived of as development progresses. This seems like a horribly messy and unmaintainable solution, especially if the number of different monster types vary in the hundreds and difference between each type isn't nearly great enough to warrant a new subclass

-Rather, my solution would be as follows:
1. Have a file that can be added to containing data for all the different `Monster` types and their characteristics in a table. The table could be added to at any time in the development of the project.

1. Write a function to load data from the table into a `Monster` object.
2. Write an initialization call at the start of the program, possibly in some sort of `MonsterManager` class, to parse the file and create a static or member vector of instantiated `Monster` objects with all the "base" statistics filled in from the table in the file (ie, starting hitpoints, etc)
3. Whenever I want to instantiate a new `Monster` of some type to add to someone's army or have someone meet with, choose a `Monster` out of the vector (randomly or via some detemining factor) create a new `Monster` object, and copy it out of the vector

Does this make sense as a solution or am I out to lunch? If this is not a good solution, what better methods are there?

Other supplemental questions:

-Would it make sense to make a different class for the monster data that would be held in the vector? I thought I could have a class called `MonsterData` that would be built into a vector by the `MonsterManager` above. I could pass to a `MonsterData` object to the constructor of the `Monster` class to actually create `Monster` objects, since a lot of `Monster` objects' characteristics would be determined by their monster-types (MaxHP, speed, etc) and other stuff would vary (CurrentHP, any randomized variables, etc)

-I thought this method would be optimizable since you could do things like add an entry to the table indicating which levels the monsters show up in, and then have the `MonsterManager` initialization function only load all monsters from certain levels at once to shrink the memory footprint)
-Since I'm not using an `enum` for this, does storing a text string make sense as a means of identifying the `Monster` object's "type"? Perhaps a pointer to the `Monster` (or `MonsterData`) it was copied from in the `MonsterManager`'s vector would be better?

I used the game analogy because it is what makes the most sense to me here, but I'd like to know the best design pattern for this kind of thing in any situation.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance should be used for modifying/adding *behaviour*, not for varying data values. In your example, it seems that each monster is defined by a set of attributes (HP, attack etc.) and you want to instantiate different monster types within the game. You don't really need inheritance for this.

You're on the right track with your `MonsterData` class; here's how I would go about it (mostly just different names for classes which I think are more meaningful):

```
// This is what you called MonsterData
// It describes how to create a monster of a specific type
public class MonsterDescription {
  private String type;   // eg. "Goblin"
  private int maxHitPoints;
  private int speed;
  ...
}

// This is an "active" instance of a monster
public class Monster {
  private int currentHitPoints;
  ...

  // static factory method
  public static Monster create(MonsterDescription desc) {
    ...
  }
}

// This is kind of what you called MonsterManager
// Contains a collection of MonsterDescription, loaded from somewhere
public class MonsterDescriptionRepository {
  // finds the description for a given type of monster
  public MonsterDescription find(String type) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And then here's how you would instantiate a new monster:

```
MonsterDescription desc = repository.find("Goblin");
Monster monster = Monster.create(desc);
```

Comment: +1: this is the [type-object pattern](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/dpa/typeobject.pdf), and it's about creating a _knowledge level_ describing the characteristics of a group of instances (similar to a "meta-object").

Answer (score 2):

the dataloader approach seems to fit your problem - it makes it easily extendable.
i would recommend to create subclasses for diferrent functionalities - for example, create a FlyingMonster subclass which will handle Dragon but not Goblin or Shark
this way you can (try) to avoid having a single Monster class which can fly/run/dive ;)

your last question was about external data keying - for this i think the pointer approach would be the best:

- it's unique
- it can help debugging
- you can optionally use the stored values from the store
- it will show the 'is_a' connection to the ancestor

note: i don't think you should 'care' with any performance issues (load them into memory to reduce memory footprint) at this stage, because it's usually breaks the design